# How to return double's and a string from a different me

Tags: java

I need to find if the three numbers make a triangle and what kind of triangle it is. So i have another java file that does that for me.

```
package atriangle;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TriangleTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double side1;
        double side2;
        double side3;
        String typeOfTriangle = "";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Side1: ");
        side1 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Side2: ");
        side2 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Side3: ");
        side3 = input.nextDouble();
        Triangle  tester = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3, typeOfTriangle);
        System.out.print("\nTriangle(" + side1 +"," + side2 + "," + side3 + ") " + typeOfTriangle);
    }
}
```

tester goes to the triangle java file to answer the above question for me

```
package atriangle;

class Triangle
{
    public Triangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC, String typeOfTriangle)
    {
        double bigside;
        double leg;
        double arm;

        if(sideA>sideB)
        {
            if(sideA > sideC)
            {
                bigside = sideA;
                leg = sideB;
                arm = sideC;
                if (isTriangle(arm, leg, bigside, typeOfTriangle)== true)
                {
                    if (isRight(arm, leg, bigside, typeOfTriangle)== true)
                    {
                        return;//return is right
                    }
                    {
                        return;//return a triangle
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sideA = 1.0;
                    sideB = 1.0;
                    sideC = 1.0;
                    return;//return not a triangle
                }
            }
            else
            {
                bigside = sideC;
                leg = sideB;
                arm = sideA;
                if (isTriangle(arm, leg, bigside, typeOfTriangle)== true)
                {
                    if (isRight(arm, leg, bigside, typeOfTriangle)== true)
                    {
                        return;//return is right
                    }
                    {
                        return;//return a triangle
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sideA = 1.0;
                    sideB = 1.0;
                    sideC = 1.0;
                    return;//return not a triangle
                }
            }
        }
        if (sideB > sideC)
        {
            bigside =sideB;
            leg = sideA;
            arm = sideC;
            if (isTriangle(arm, leg, bigside, typeOfTriangle)== true)
                {
                    if (isRight(arm, leg, bigside, typeOfTriangle)== true)
                    {
                        typeOfTriangle = "is right";
                        return;//return is right
                    }
                    {
                        return;//return a triangle
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sideA = 1.0;
                    sideB = 1.0;
                    sideC = 1.0;
                    return;//return not a triangle
                }
        }
        if(sideC > sideA)
        {
            bigside = sideC;
            leg = sideB;
            arm = sideA;
            if (isTriangle(arm, leg, bigside, typeOfTriangle)== true)
                {
                    if (isRight(arm, leg, bigside, typeOfTriangle)== true)
                    {
                        typeOfTriangle = "is right";
                        return;//return is right
                    }
                    {
                        return;//return a triangle
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sideA = 1.0;
                    sideB = 1.0;
                    sideC = 1.0;
                    return;//return not a triangle
                }
        }
        else
        {
            typeOfTriangle = "is equalaterial";
            return;//return is equalaterial
        }
    }
    public static boolean isTriangle(double arm, double leg, double bigside, String typeOfTriangle)
    {
        if (arm + leg > bigside)
        {
            return true;
        }
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static boolean isRight(double leg, double arm, double bigside, String typeOfTriangle)
    {
        if (leg*leg + arm*arm == bigside*bigside)
        {
            return true;
        }
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to return the new value of String typeOfTriangle. Can anyone please tell me how i return String typeOfTriangle and doubles: sideA, sideB, sideC?

Comment: A constructor does not return anything, please check a Java book/tutorial. If you want a method to create and return objects, you might be looking for a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Also in method `isTriangle`: `return (arm + leg > bigside);` is enough, no need `if`; same for the other method `isRight`.

Comment: I *highly* suggest browsing through the [official tutorial on classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html). It is well-written and will give you all of the tools you need to solve this problem and others like it. There is also the [specific section on methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html), if you want to glance at that first, but I do recommend reading the main section in its entirety. A good answer to your question would be very long here, and would pretty much just duplicate those tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is How your Triangle Class should look like :

```
class Triangle
{
private double bigside;
private double leg;
private double arm;

public Triangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC)
{

    if(sideA>sideB)
    {
        if(sideA > sideC)
        {
            bigside = sideA;
            leg = sideB;
            arm = sideC;
        }
        else
        {
            bigside = sideC;
            leg = sideB;
            arm = sideA;
        }
    }
    if (sideB > sideC)
    {
        bigside =sideB;
        leg = sideA;
        arm = sideC;
    }
    if(sideC > sideA)
    {
        bigside = sideC;
        leg = sideB;
        arm = sideA;
    }
}

public String typeOfTriangle() {
     if (isTriangle(arm, leg, bigside )== true)
    {
        if (isRight(arm, leg, bigside )== true)
        {
            return "is Right";
        }
        else    {
            return "A triangle";
            }
    }
    else    {
        arm = 1.0;
        leg = 1.0;
        bigside = 1.0;
        return "Not a triangle";
    }
     return "is Equilateral";
}


public static boolean isTriangle(double arm, double leg, double bigside)
{
    if (arm + leg > bigside)
    {
        return true;
    }
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public static boolean isRight(double leg, double arm, double bigside)
{
    if (leg*leg + arm*arm == bigside*bigside)
    {
        return true;
    }
    {
        return false;
    }
   }
}
```

In your main if you want to call it and print it you should change the last two lines like follow:

```
    Triangle  tester = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);
    System.out.print("\nTriangle(" + side1 +"," + side2 + "," + side3 + ")" + tester.typeOfTriangle();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, but with the code that you already have, I would create a Java enum called "TriangleType" that contains each type of triangle, and then I would add a static method to your Triangle class that returns one of the enum types when you pass in the three sides as parameters. Then you could add a class member to your Triangle class called "type" that could call this method in the constructor so every instance of Triangle will know what type of triangle it is. Here's a quick modification of your code which is not tested so there are probably syntax errors.

```
public enum TriangleType {
    NOT_A_TRIANGLE("Not a triangle"),
    RIGHT("Right"),
    EQUILATERAL("Equilateral"),
    ISOSCELES("Isosceles"),
    SCALENE("Scalene");

    private String name;

    TriangleType(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Then the Triangle class.

```
class Triangle
{
    private int sideA;
    private int sideB;
    private int sideC;
    private TriangleType type;

    public Triangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC)
    {
        this.sideA = sideA;
        this.sideB = sideB;
        this.sideC = sideC;
        this.type = Triangle::getTriangleType(sideA, sideB, sideC);
    }

    public TriangleType getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public static TriangleType getTriangleType(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC) {

        double bigside;
        double leg;
        double arm;

        if(sideA>sideB)
        {
            if(sideA > sideC)
            {
                bigside = sideA;
                leg = sideB;
                arm = sideC;
                if (isTriangle(arm, leg, bigside)== true)
                {
                    if (isRight(arm, leg, bigside)== true)
                    {
                        return TriangleType.RIGHT;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return TriangleType.NOT_A_TRIANGLE;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                bigside = sideC;
                leg = sideB;
                arm = sideA;
                if (isTriangle(arm, leg, bigside)== true)
                {
                    if (isRight(arm, leg, bigside)== true)
                    {
                        return TriangleType.RIGHT;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return TriangleType.NOT_A_TRIANGLE;
                }
            }
        }
        if (sideB > sideC)
        {
            bigside =sideB;
            leg = sideA;
            arm = sideC;
            if (isTriangle(arm, leg, bigside)== true)
                {
                    if (isRight(arm, leg, bigside)== true)
                    {
                        return TriangleType.RIGHT;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return TriangleType.NOT_A_TRIANGLE;
                }
        }
        if(sideC > sideA)
        {
            bigside = sideC;
            leg = sideB;
            arm = sideA;
            if (isTriangle(arm, leg, bigside)== true)
                {
                    if (isRight(arm, leg, bigside)== true)
                    {
                        return TriangleType.RIGHT;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return TriangleType.NOT_A_TRIANGLE;
                }
        }
        else
        {
            return TriangleType.EQUILATERAL;
        }
    }
    public static boolean isTriangle(double arm, double leg, double bigside)
    {
        if (arm + leg > bigside)
        {
            return true;
        }
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static boolean isRight(double leg, double arm, double bigside)
    {
        if (leg*leg + arm*arm == bigside*bigside)
        {
            return true;
        }
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And your main method.

```
public class TriangleTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double side1;
        double side2;
        double side3;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Side1: ");
        side1 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Side2: ");
        side2 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Side3: ");
        side3 = input.nextDouble();

        Triangle tester = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);

        System.out.print("\nTriangle(" + side1 +"," + side2 + "," + side3 + ") " + tester.getType());
    }
}
```